# Accessing a ColdFusion datasource from Java code

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, coldfusion

I have a servlet that I would like to run within ColdFusion MX 7. I would like to make use of an existing ColdFusion DSN as a javax.sql.DataSource, if possible.

I thought something like

```
coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory.getDataSourceService().getDatasource(dsname);
```

would work, but unfortunately the servlet returns

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: coldfusion/server/ServiceFactory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the simplest way to do this is to add an additional JNDI datasource into jrun-resources.xml. This can then be accessed in the conventional way:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("mydatasource");
```

It does mean duplicating database connection configuration, but I would rather do this than work with the largely undocumented coldfusion.server.* classes.

Answer (score 1):

That code will work fine, you just don't have ServiceFactory in your classpath. Ie, Java can't load that class. Try including a dependency on cfusion.jar from C:\CFusionMX7\lib.

Comment: Now getting: coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory$ServiceNotAvailableException: The DataSource service is not available. neo-query.xml is fine, queries from .cfm pages still work.

Comment: Hmm, I have only done this is a java class being called from ColdFusion with CFOBJECT. Is that what you're doing? You may need to be in that context to get to the datasources.

Comment: It is looking that way. I've got a servlet that needs access to a database. I'll see if creating a new JNDI datasource in jrun-resources.xml works, should do.